# How can I automate adding users to groups in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

This is after a user asks to view a certain page, folder, or file. Depending on the page or file the user requested to view, after I approve a request I want SharePoint to add the user to a specific group.

Example: 
User requested to view Page1. I approve. Page1 selected so User is added to Viewer group. 
NewUser requests to view Page2. I approve. Page2 selected so NewUser is added to the Members group.

Comment: how do the users add this requests to view page or folder or file? is it some custom list with all of the requests? or are You using some OOTB functionality? If the request is some kind of new item on the list maybe the best approach would be and event receiver. Please provide a bit more detail to the problem

Comment: It's all OOTB functionality with a layer of security slapped on top so I can't change the source code or tenant, but I have my site's admin rights.

Comment: maybe I don't seem to understand :). If we are talking about OOTB manage access rights feature then when a site owner approves a request to access the site he or she may pick to add permission via group or directly (not recommended). Adding to group after approval works automatically. here a couple of links to the feature I refer to:
http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-a-look-at-requesting-site-access
   
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/manage-access-request-settings-in-sharepoint-2013.html
   
https://www.maadarani.com/sharepoint-online-managing-access-requests-draft-ah/

Comment: Maybe I'm not good at explaining. I want to accept access requests similar to how it's shown on this: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/manage-access-request-settings-in-sharepoint-2013.html...... But I want another step from the pending access requests screen to add to a specific group. Ideally I want that extra step automated. Does that explain it better?

Comment: on the acceptance popup window you should have a link to more options in the bottom of the form click it and you should be able to select to which group you need to add that user.